# Create a repeat region for a column when displaying data from database rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to be able to retrieve data from a DB and display it in column, however the first column in the table are the headings for example

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td><input name="number" type="text" id="number" value="<?php echo $row_get['Number']; ?>" size="7" />;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Boxed</td>
      <td><input name="Boxed" type="text" id="Location" value="<?php echo $row_get['Boxed']; ?>" size="7" />;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td><input name="Location" type="text" id="Location" value="<?php echo $row_get['Location']; ?>" size="7" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td><input name="Quantity" type="text" id="Quantity" value="<?php echo $row_get['Quantity']; ?>" size="7" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Retrieving from DB:**

```
$query_get = "SELECT * FROM Stock ORDER BY Model";
$getget = $conn->query($query_get) or die(ErrorInfo());
// Here we have the total row count
$row = $get->rowCount();
```

How can I repeat the 2nd column for the next row of data that is retrieved from the database and keep the first column as static headers.

I know you can repeat the row by doing the following:

```
 <?php do { ?><tr><td></td>
<td></td></tr> <?php } while ($row_get = ->fetch()); ?>
```

**output that I would like,
rows are taken from db query**

```
  Number    Row 1, Number   Row 2, Number   Row 3, Number   etc 
    Boxed   Row 1 Boxed     Row 2  Boxed    Row 3  Boxed    etc 
    Location    Row 1 Location  Row 2 Location  Row 3 Location  etc 
    Quantity    Row 1 Quantity  Row 2 Quantity  Row 3 Quantity  etc
```

But how would you do that for a column?
Any help welcome

Comment: Can you make it clear with an example or few rows of data?

Comment: @Ajith please see edit in question hope that helps

Comment: Sorry stil not clear.. Number is repeating through first row on each colum ?

Comment: @Ajith I am getting more than 1 row returned from my data base so row 1 contains a number field, a Boxed field,  a location field and a Quantity field. This will be for every row retrieved from the DB. All I want to do is display this in a table where the left column is static Number, Boxed, Location, Quantity) and the next columns display the different rows retrieved from the data base

Comment: Sorry for late reply ! Still face issue? If so I can help you